# Does Apple allow requesting promo codes for apps rated 17+?

Tags: app-store-connect, promotion-code

My only app with a 17+ rating has the "Request Promo Codes" button disabled in iTunes Connect.  I checked Google before contacting Apple and it seems that in 2009 Apple temporarily disabled promo codes for 17+ apps.  Does anybody know if this is in effect again?

I have checked the following:

- I didn't use all the app's promo codes
- My user has the required "legal" status

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is the case. I don't know why, but since about last weekend, it's no longer possible to create promo codes for 17+ Apps. I've contacted Apple to ask them about this, and they confirmed that this is the case.

I've already asked Apple if they can change this again, and hopefully some more developers will do this.